# change url of the contact page in form.phtml file in magento

Tags: contact-us

the contact us page url is "contacts" in this site : http://demo.kidsdial.com/CONTACTS

this is the code : http://pastebin.com/eWDcbi0W

in above code, where i have to change "contacts " to "contact-us" to change the "url"

of that "contact" page.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change the contact us page URL from `contacts` to `contact-us` or need to redirect URL referencing `contact-us` to `contacts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered on StackOverflow, I'll quote:

> 1. In the Catalog menu click on URL Rewrite Management.
> 2. Click the Add URL Rewrite button.
> 3. Choose to add a Custom type.
> 4. Enter "contacts" for ID Path and Target Path.
> 5. Enter "**contact-us**" for the Request Path.
> 6. Click the Save button.

<sup>**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/5897601/664108</sup>

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: This is a redirect, in the final url you see "contacts"

Answer (score 5):

Create a file in `app/etc/modules/Kp_Contacts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kp_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Kp_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create the config file in `app/code/local/Kp/Contacts/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kp_Contacts>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Kp_Contacts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Contacts</module>
                    <frontName>contact-us</frontName>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

That’s it upload the files and clear the cache. Yea the default Magento url changed to new one

Your new URL will be http://yourdomain.com/contact-us

Comment: Upvote for Greate Answer....!

Comment: This works but once the form is submitted the user is returned to /contact-us/index/ i.e. the controller action is added to the URL. Any ideas how or whether that can be fixed?

Comment: you have to update success url from block which is used in form
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />

Answer (score 1):

If this is the CMS page(what i assumed) then you can directly give the specific url key in CMS->Pages.

Comment: unfortunately, in this theme they did't put contact_us under pages....

Comment: So where you have created? is this the category ?

Comment: no, it's displaying from the theme file = contacts/form.phtml

Comment: Did anybody find a solution? have the same issue